# Cannot upgrade gradle wrapper from version 2.1 to 6.5.1

Tags: gradle, upgrade, gradlew, gradle-2, gradle-6.5.1

I have an old project with Gradle 2.1. Today I want to "upgrade" the gradle wrapper version to 6.5.1, so I used this:

```
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.5.1
```

But the output is:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :wrapper from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--gradle-version'.

* Try:
Run gradlew help --task :wrapper to get task usage details. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with                                                                                                                      --info                                                                                                                   or                                                                                                                     --debug                                                                                                                  option to get more log output.
```

Seems like the param --gradle-version was not available at that time (2.1). Tried a lot googling without any luck. Could you please show me how to overcome this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually edit `<prj_home>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

set `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip`

then `./gradlew wrapper` will work